# Proof of $\{X\le a\} = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} \{X \le x_{n}\} $ , for $x_{n} \downarrow a$

Tags: real-analysis

Let : $$X : Ω \to \mathbb R ~,~ a \in \mathbb R ~,~x :\mathbb N \to \mathbb  R ~,~ x_{n} \downarrow a $$
How can I prove formally that : $$\{X\le a\} = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} \{X \le x_{n}\}$$ 
For clarity :$$\{X\le a\} = \{ω\in Ω ~{|}~ X(ω)\le a \}$$
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you wrote $X\le x$, did you mean $X\le a$?

Comment: @José Carlos Santos Yes , I will correct it .

Comment: I think your writing is far too formal.  You need words and not symbols.

Comment: I think you can make your solution shorter, thinking more axiomatically is good, but the solution becomes clumsy.

Comment: After long consideration I agree that my solution is clumsy and too formal . I delete it because your answers already answer the question and my solution does not add new information on how to solve the question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X(\omega)\le a$, then, since $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):a\le x_n$, $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):X(\omega)\le x_n$; in other words, $\omega\in\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\{X\le x_n\}$.

On the other hand, if $\omega\in\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\{X\le x_n\}$, then $X(\omega)\le x_n$, for every $n\in\mathbb N$. Since $\lim_{n\in\mathbb N}x_n=a$ and that $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):a\le x_n$, it follows that $X(\omega)\le a$.

Comment: For the premises I have given the following statement is also valid : $$\{X\le a\} = \bigcap_{ n \in \mathbb N}\{X \le x_n\} = \bigcap_{ n \in \mathbb N}\{X < x_n\}$$Am I correct ? I do honestly see no mistake .

Comment: @liaguridio Yes, this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

We could analyze this into two parts ...

(1) a fact about intervals of real numbers
$$
(-\infty, a] = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} \;(-\infty, x_n]
$$
(2) a fact about inverse images
$$
X^{-1}\left(\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} E_n\right)\;=\;
\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} X^{-1}(E_n)
$$

Do you have doubts about one of these?

Answer (score 0):

Let $A_n=\{X\leq x_n\}$, $A_1\supset A_2\supset \dots$

Using continuity of sets $A_n$ decreases to $\cap_n A_n.$

Now $A_n\supset \{X\leq a\}$, for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, and if $A_n$ decreases to $\{X\leq y\}$, and $a<y$, then there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $a<x_{N+1}\leq y\leq x_N$. Thus $A_{N+1}\subset \{X\leq y\}$, which contradict the continuity of those sets. Hence $A_n$ decreases to $\{X\leq a\}$.

Hence $$\{X\le a\} = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} \{X \le x_{n}\} $$